# Rails convert secrets to credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I updated my Rails app from 5.1.6 to 5.2.1 and we were using `secrets` before. We'd like to switch to `credentials` since it was supposed to replace `secrets`. There are a couple of things I'm wondering:

1) Is there a "Railsy" way to do this? I'm aware I can just edit the `secrets` and copy the contents over to the `credentials` but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it since I couldn't find anything that talks about this. Also, I tried copy the encrypted content from `secrets.yml.enc` and paste it to `credentials.yml.enc` but that didn't work, ran into some issues with the encryption.

2) Related to the first point, am I supposed to still be able to use `secrets` in 5.2.1? I thought `credentials` was supposed to replace `secrets` so I was surprised I could still use `secrets` and all my tests are passing.

Thanks for any info or help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Backup your config/secrets.yml. Scaffold a temporary vanilla Rails 5.2.1 project via rails new. Copy config/master.key and config/credentials.yml.enc from it to your existing Rails project. Edit these credentials e.g in Ubuntu via:

```
EDITOR="gedit --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Replace the secret_key_base (new flat format prefered, optional for all environments) from the old secrets.yml and / or paste whatever else you need as a secret into it and save it. Delete config/secrets.yml and the temporary Rails project. Access the secrets in your code e.g. via:

```
Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base
```

Ensure that your upgraded Rails 5.1.6 project use the master key in config/environments/*.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.require_master_key = true
  ...
end
```

Restart the Rails server. Do'nt forget to .gitignore and .dockerignore the config/master.key!